# Kosher for Pesach substitutes – aren't they too real?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

I was always bothered by the fact that some Pesach food (cookies and the like) looks very real, almost like the original.

Are there any authorities who have taken this as an actual issue? Isn't it possible to have an understanding of the talmudic principle *taam k'ikar* that it applies to that case?

I am aware that one could easily differentiate and say that *taam k'ikar* applies only when it actually comes from that same exact material, but still.

Are the Rishonim speaking out this distinction? Are there talmudic precedents of similar food substitutes where it is mefurash that they are not subject of taam k'ikar?

Comment: Isn’t there a fish that tastes like pork that is presented in the gemara? Medrash? as a good thing, an expression of the breadth of hashems creation.

Comment: @mroll "_Isn’t there a fish that tastes like pork that is presented in the gemara_"? Yes, [there is](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.109b.13?lang=bi&lang2=en): the [brains of a] shibuta fish. More generally, [chullin 109b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.109b.12?lang=bi&lang2=en) brings, "אמרה ליה ילתא לרב נחמן מכדי כל דאסר לן רחמנא שרא לן כוותיה" ("_Yalta said to_ [her husband] _Rav Naḥman: Now_ [as a rule, for] _any_ [item] _that the Merciful One prohibited to us, He permitted to us a similar_ [item]"), and lists examples for this rule.

Comment: [Similar.](/q/81156)

Comment: Cookies aren't inherently chametz (there's no rising/fermentation), so it's no surprise that you can manufacture them for pesach. Find me imitation sourdough bread that's KP and we'll talk.

Comment: See Rashi Chulin 98b ד"ה לטעם, and Sefer Hachinuch mitzvah 368.